# How to change the title of dynamically created element using vuex mutation?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm really confused because of some reason I can't manipulate the title of dynamically added element. The title is changing for all elements I've create in process.

Here is what I want to achieve: I want be able to call n number of components and then manipulate the title of specific one independently.

In my example vuex receives proper indexes of detail goal so I don't understand why `DG_TITLE_MUTATION` changes the names of all detail goals. And more when I get main object form server with already two details goals I can change there names as I wanted but story repeat with new element that been created in session.

Please help me I'm stuck here really badly.

First component with v-for directive here I'm add and display the problematic components

```
<template>


    <q-btn icon="add" label="add detail goal" @click="addDetailGoal"/>

    <q-list v-for="(detailGoal, index) in $store.state.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals" :key="index" :name="index">
      <goals-details :thisIndex="index"/>  
    </q-list>    
 
</template>
<script lang="ts">
//jj. Main import
import { defineComponent} from 'vue';
//jj. Components
import GoalsDetails from './GoalsDetails.vue';
//jj. Store
import { useStore } from 'src/store';
//jj. types
import { detailGoal } from './models'

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'NewDocument',
    components:{
      GoalsDetails
    },
    props:{
      grantObj:{
        type: Object
      },
    },

    setup() {
    
    //jj. main settings
    const store = useStore()

    //jj.  This is part pushed to main object when user use add main goal btn
    const detailGoal:detailGoal= {
      id:'',
      title:'New detail goal',
      description:'',
      quote:'',
      tasks:[],
    };       

    //jj. Add addDetailGoal
    function addDetailGoal(){ 
      store.commit('ADD_DETAIL_GOAL', detailGoal) 
    }

    return { 
      //jj. functions
      addDetailGoal,
    };
  },
})
</script>
```

Here is component with title to manipulate with input connected with mutation function

```
<template>
<q-btn icon="delete" label="delete" @click="removeDetailGoal" class="bg-purple text-white"/>
    <q-input v-model="detailGoalTitle" label="Project title" class="q-ml-sm"/>
<script lang="ts">
//jj. vue
import { defineComponent, ref, computed} from 'vue';
//jj. components
import ProjectTasks from 'components/ProjectTasks.vue'
//jj. types
import { task } from './models'
//jj. Store
import { useStore } from 'src/store';

export default defineComponent({
  
  name: 'GoalsDetails',
  props:{
    thisIndex:{
      type: Number
    },
  },
  components:{
    ProjectTasks,
  },
  setup(thisIndex) {
    const store = useStore()

    // *******************************************************************************************
    // jj. DETAIL GOAL SECTION
    // *******************************************************************************************
    //jj. Edit detail goal title 
    let detailGoalTitle = computed({
      get: () => {
        if(store.state.documents && typeof thisIndex.thisIndex == 'number'){
          return store.state.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals[thisIndex.thisIndex].title}else{
        return 'no document'
      }},
      set:( val ) => store.commit('DG_TITLE_MUTATION', {val, thisIndex})
    })


    function removeDetailGoal(){
      store.commit('REMOVE_DETAIL_GOAL', thisIndex.thisIndex)
    }
    // *******************************************************************************************
    // jj. TASKS SECTION
    // *******************************************************************************************
    //jj.  This is part pushed to main object when user use add main goal btn
    const taskTemplate:task= {
          id:'', 
          title:'New Task',
          results:[]
    };
    
    //jj. Add Task
      function addTask(){
      console.log(thisIndex.thisIndex);// this is proper index
      store.commit( 'ADD_TASK', {taskTemplate, thisIndex} )
    }


    return { 
      //jj. detail goal section
      detailGoalTitle, 
      removeDetailGoal,
    };
  },
})
</script>
```

vuex

```
//jj. Add next detailGoal
      ADD_DETAIL_GOAL(store, detailGoal: detailGoal){
        if(store.documents){store.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals.push(detailGoal)}
      },

      //jj. Edit detail goal title
      DG_TITLE_MUTATION( store, {val, thisIndex}:{val:string, thisIndex:{thisIndex:number}}){
        if(store.documents){store.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals[thisIndex.thisIndex].title = val 
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to James from another forum i know the answer.
My mistake were came from wrong useage of javascript.
I've pass the detailGoal whitch is only reference to the specific object not the new one. Here:

```
 function addDetailGoal(){ 
 store.commit('ADD_DETAIL_GOAL', detailGoal) 
}
```

To pass the new object I sholud create a function to do so:

```
function detailGoal():detailGoal{ 
 {
   id:'',
   title:'New detail goal',
   description:'',
   quote:'',
   tasks:[],
  };       
};

 function addDetailGoal(){ 
 store.commit('ADD_DETAIL_GOAL', detailGoal()) 
}
```